# Hibernate can not write data to mysql correctly

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to write some information about the user who opens the web application which i made. The web app is simple. When open it it shows users ip, user-agent, and the time of the last log into the app. I`ve made this app with these technologies: Spring, Maven, Tomcat, Hibernate and MySQL. It seems that everything is working correctly but when i open the app in browser in do note make a record to Data Base and i must start manually Main.java to make a record but the record is no correct because it does not record the real information but it record NULL everywhere. I have two questions - How to do all this automatically (when i open the web app to have a record in DB) and Why my records are every time NULL.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
        user.setRollNo(7);
        user.setIp(UserController.ip);
        user.setUserAgent(UserController.userAgent);
        user.setDate((Date) UserController.date);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
   @Controller
    public class UserController {

        public static String ip;
        public static String userAgent;
        public static Date date;

        @Autowired
        private HttpServletRequest request;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/connection")
        public ModelAndView getUserInfo() {

            ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("UserInfo");

            ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
            modelandView.addObject("msg1", "Your IP is " + ip);

            userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
            modelandView.addObject("msg2", "Your User agent is " + userAgent);

            date = new java.util.Date();
            /*
             * Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); java.sql.Date startDate =
             * new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime() .getTime());
             */
            modelandView.addObject("msg3", "Your last log was at " + date);

            return modelandView;

        }

    }
```

UserInfo.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_INFORMATION")
public class UserInfo {

    @Id
    private int rollNo;
    private String ip;
    private String userAgent;
    private Date date;

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public String getUserAgent() {
        return userAgent;
    }

    public void setUserAgent(String userAgent) {
        this.userAgent = userAgent;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/browserinfo</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <mapping class="com.nikola.hellocontroller.UserInfo" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to achieve? You want to get some data from database and display it in view? Or maybe create new user and store it in database? How do you want to achieve this without any data access layer?

Comment: The way you're performing that "logging" is really strange. why do you store the information from `getUserInfo` in `static` variables? They will be overwritten by every request. And yes you have to trigger the `main` method manually, because your database handling is only there. And the database entry will contain `null` if you do not access `/connection` first. And now I wonder why you've implemented it that way if you don't want that.

Comment: And what's the purpose of using database in this example? You are retrieving user info from request, and then what? You want to create new user and store it in db? And what next? Retrieve it from database? By what? By primary key you don't know?

Comment: @novy154
I want to record some data and after that display it to view.


@Tom
I am now learning this technologies now. I decide to make a theme here because i need some help.. i`am still noob. If you have some time to explain me how to fix this mess I would be very grateful.

Comment: @novy154
I am trying to make e record to DB with the users IP, user-agent info and the time when the user was lastloged in the app. After that i want to display all records in the app.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

> @novy154 I am trying to make e record to DB with the users IP, user-agent info and the time when the user was lastloged in the app. After that i want to display all records in the app.

First of all, you need to have some DataAccessLayer. Something like

```
public interface UserInfoRepository {
    void save(UserInfo userInfo);
    Collection<UserInfo> findAll();
}
```

and it's implementation.

Then maybe some service over the Repository, but it doesn't matter in this case, so let's skip it.

You need to inject your repository into controller and:

1) invoke `userInfoRepository.save(newlyCreatedUserInfo)`

2) pass all UserInfos to your view (by invoking `userInfoRepository.findAll()` and putting the result in modelAndView) and display it somehow.

Let me know if you need help implementing this.

But this is just in purpose of learning how to make simple crud-like application, cause this doesn't make any sense. You can't even identify your user, you just want to track each visitor's ip, user info and so on.

// edit: 
Repository implementation would be something like:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserInfoRepositoryImpl implements UserInfoRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void save(UserInfo userInfo) {
        getCurrentSession.save(userInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<UserInfo> findAll() {

        final Criteria root = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserInfo.class);
        return Collections.checkedList(root.list(), UserInfo.class);
    }

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

Then in your controller method you need to invoke `save(newlyCreatedUserInfo)` to store your info in the database and

```
modelAndView.addObject("userInfos", repository.findAll());
```

to retrieve all data and pass it to a view.

Of course remember about

```
...
@Autowired
private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;
...
```

in controller.

Note that since spring-data-jpa provides you more powerful repositories out of the box, this is reinventing a wheel.

Comment: I do not want to identify the user. I want to make it max simple. I want to record in the DB all users info (ip, user-agent ..) and display it. For now i do not want to make a registration and identification for users.

Comment: Then implementing some kind of data access layer is the way to go.

Comment: Will you plase give me an example to understand how to do that because i`ve read so much information and watch a lot of tutorials.... and now it`s very big mess in my head ... :(